# javascript src does not work from parent jquery load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a parent container loading in a child container which has javascript `src` pointing to a library.  When the child is loaded, the `src` library does not run. 
I tried `getScript()` after callback but this does not have any affect. 
The library is a color picker: http://jscolor.com/ 
Any suggestions please? 
parent.html:

```
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        $('#rec').load('child.html', function(){
          $.getScript("js/jscolor.js");
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='rec'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

child.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jscolor.js"></script>
<input class="color" value="66ff00">
```

Comment: What do you see in the dev tools?

Comment: My psychic debugging skills tell me that you have a 404 due to relative path issues.

Comment: @SLaks do you mean console?  the child is loaded but the JS does not work.

Comment: @SLaks i dont see a 404,  when i place the content of child in parent for testing it all works

Comment: what is in js file, because i am able to run something like this in my system.

Comment: If was a dinamic page with many js libraries possibilities ok, but if that is all that you want, why not call `jscolor` in your parent page together with `jquery` ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown  just tried that but with no luck

Comment: Then you have a strange behaviour. Check paths, erros, whatever, cause I work in a project that uses tons of nested ajax loaded divs and just one js call at the beggining..

Comment: Not even jQuery codes works inside your `child.html` ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown  `jquery` works,  so theres something in the color picker that wont accept dynamic elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jscolor.js needs to loaded before document is completly loaded because it attach stuffs to `input` element using onload event of document, in your case document is already loaded when you load jscolor.js. So call `jscolor.init` again after `$.getScript("js/jscolor.js")` has loaded the js file.

```
$(function(){
$('#rec').load('child.html', function(){
   $.getScript("js/jscolor.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
       jscolor.init();
});
```